# Why is Betzalel (the constructor of the mishkan), only mentioned after the entire building process of the mishkan?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mishkan-tabernacle, parashat-ki-tisa

Being that in Parashat Terumah and a portion of Tezaveh discusses the building of the Mishkan with all its vessels, the Torah hadn't told us who the constructor of the Mishkan was until Parashat Ki Tisa. In Parshat Ki Tisa 31:2 it says, "רְאֵ֖ה קָרָ֣אתִֽי בְשֵׁ֑ם בְּצַלְאֵ֛ל בֶּן־אוּרִ֥י בֶן־ח֖וּר לְמַטֵּ֥ה יְהוּדָֽה׃", "See, I have singled out by name Bezalel son of Uri son of Hur, of the tribe of Judah." My question is, why does the Torah wait until now to mention who the constructor of the Mishkan was? It would make more sense for it to be mentioned before the building, just like knowing who the builder is before building a house?

Comment: Avishai Tebeka, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing this intriguing question here! I hope you'll take a look at our other [tag:parshanut-torah-comment] content, and I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: "Being that in Parashat Terumah and a portion of Tezaveh discusses the building of the Mishkan with all its vessels" Is that the case? Why do you say that? I see building only in Vayaqhel and Pekudei. Maybe I missed something

Comment: @DoubleAA the building is only later, but the Torah does discuss the building earlier.